# Spring Security and the Proper Way to Verify that User has Access to a Resource

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security which works great to make sure that a user has a certain role before accessing a resource. But now I need to verify something a little different:

```
`/product/edit/{productId}`
```

**What is the best way to verify that the logged in user "owns" `productId`?** My business mappings handle the relationship (a `user` has a list of `products`). I need to verify this product belongs to the user and hence, they can edit it.

I know how to gain access to `productId` and the logged in user in both the controller and an interceptor. I don't believe this logic belongs in the controller at all. The interceptor seems better but I wondered if Spring Security had an "accepted" way of handling this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Spring you can implement this by implementing Access Control Lists. ACL declaration specifies permissions for individual objects per user. Once you have everything setup like acl entries in your database and logic, you can use SpEL and @PostFilter annotation to control the list of objects returned to a user.

[Spring Security Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/domain-acls.html)

[Related:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067496/spring-acl-for-jsf/9070071#9070071)